# How to check value of data in javascript?

Tags: javascript, ajax

How can I check the value of "data"? I have some problem with the data because it is empty when I parsing it.

```
$.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'proses.php?page=tambah',
        data: "jobtitle="+jobtitle+"&description="+description+"&need="+need+"&ids="+ids,

    });
```

Comment: you dont send data like this in ajax

Comment: @ShubhDixit — `data:` can take a string. It's entirely valid.

Answer (score 1):

Send data as an object :

```
$.ajax({ 
    type: 'POST', 
    url: 'proses.php', 
    data: {
        page:"tambah",
        jobtitle:jobtitle,
        description:description,
        need:need,
        ids:ids
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think jQuery exposes it as a public property after you've passed it to the `ajax` method.

The simplest way to look it would be to use the Network tab of the browser's developer tools and examine the body of the outgoing XMLHttpRequest request.